# Joomla 1.5 image upload error despite successful upload

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

When uploading an image to Joomla via RSGallery2, I keep getting this message:

[image: joomla error message message]

The image shows up in the list of items so it obviously worked but clearly the upload script tried copying it to other folders and failed. Does anyone know what folders those could be? Thanks.

I wasn't the one to set up this Joomla installation. This project was just handed down to me. I'm clueless regarding Joomla.

Comment: No. IIS is only for Windows, right? The server is Linux and, I believe, running Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Check your permissions on the /tmp and /cache folder (you can do this within Joomla in an area called Directory permissions)

Comment: Where in the admin is this? Either it's under a different name in this version or the people who set up this installation managed to hide or remove it.In any case, I set both folders to 777 and the error messages still show up.

Comment: In Joomla 1.5 it's under `Help > System Info` then `Directory Permissions tab`

Comment: Now things are just getting silly. All the folders are listed as writable. Is it likely that the module is attempting to write to a folder not listed here then?